# How to get the Name of the IIS Virtual Application in a Variable of a PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-5.0

Here is the code which gets the details of all the Virtual Application present under the **Default Web Site** in IIS and displays its Physical path but fails to display the Name of the Virtual Application.

```
$WebClientPath= Get-WebApplication -Site "Default Web Site" 


foreach($Site in $WebClientPath)
{

                $S=$Site.Name
                $PhysicalPath=$Site.physicalPath
                Write-host $S
                Write-Host $PhysicalPath
}
```

What property should I use to display the Name of Virtual Application through a Variable?

Comment: Hi think you can find information on : $(Get-IISSite -Name Default).Applications.VirtualDirectories

Comment: There are only "applications" and "virtual directories", https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis So there is no "virtual application".

Comment: Can the Application be renamed using PowerShell?